# Encountered the symbol "2"

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, toad

In this procedure I want to make a list of all procedures in my code and the user chooses a number to execute a certain procedure or function.
Here's my code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calling
IS
    chosen VARCHAR2(1);
    V_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    &chosen;
    IF    chosen='1' THEN
        V_count:=visited.count_nb_city_visited(&idclient); 
    ELSIF chosen='2' THEN
        V_count:=visited.max_vis;
        visited.extract_best(V_count);
    ELSIF chosen='3' THEN
        ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CITY;
    ELSIF chosen='4' THEN
        ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CLIENT;
    END IF;
END;
```

When running the code, this warning pops up "PLS-00103: Symbol "2" encountered (if I choose the number 2 and the same error is shown with any number I choose)

Answer (score 2):

You can't (shouldn't) use substitution variables in a stored procedure as it will substitute the values in on compilation (and not as you are probably expecting on execution).

So if you substitute `2` for `&chosen` and `42` for `&idclient` then your code will be compiled as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calling
IS
    chosen VARCHAR2(1);
    V_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    2;
    IF    chosen='1' THEN
        V_count:=visited.count_nb_city_visited(42); 
    ELSIF chosen='2' THEN
        V_count:=visited.max_vis;
        visited.extract_best(V_count);
    ELSIF chosen='3' THEN
        ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CITY;
    ELSIF chosen='4' THEN
        ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CLIENT;
    END IF;
END;
```

And will always execute with those fixed values.

You are getting the error because `2;` is not a valid PL/SQL statement.

Instead, you should pass all the bind variables in the signature. Something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calling (
  chosen   IN NUMBER,
  idclient IN NUMBER
)
IS
  V_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF    chosen = 1 THEN
    V_count:=visited.count_nb_city_visited(idclient); 
  ELSIF chosen = 2 THEN
    V_count:=visited.max_vis;
    visited.extract_best(V_count);
  ELSIF chosen = 3 THEN
    ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CITY;
  ELSIF chosen = 4 THEN
    ORDER_ORIGIN_CITY.ORDER_CLIENT;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

If you want to call it from an anonymous PL/SQL block, then you can use substitution variables in that block:

```sql
BEGIN
  calling(
    chosen   => &chosen,
    idclient => &idclient
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: In this case, when calling the procedure I should enter the idclient everytime. I only need it when the user chooses 1

Comment: @mariamjallouli You cannot do that as the substitution variables all need to be substituted for the code to execute.